# VB TextBox entry handling - TAB key missing

Tags: vb.net

Windows 10/VS 2015 Community/Visual Basic 2014

I have written the following to input text from 13 TextBoxes.  It inputs
each character with its own event.  Each character is checked for being
a valid character (numerals, letters, symbols) plus Cr (to move to next
TextBox) and BS (to permit typo corrections).  This works:

---

```
'===== Enter Frequency =====

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    ichar = e.KeyChar()

    ckinchar()                                         'ck for input characters, or CR or BS keys

    If eoline = 1 Then                                  'has <cr> been detected?
        freq = inline                                   'Yes
        bufcnt = 0                                      'Reset counter
        eoline = 0                                     'Rest EOL flag
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.LightPink
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TextBox1.Focus()                                'No  - repeat inputting
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Problem:  I wish to also use the TAB key (to be implemented as the Cr key)
However the TAB key code fails to appear.  In run mode pressing the Tab key
causes the cursor to move up the displayed TextBoxs following the tabIndex order.  I've tried using KeyDown/Enter/TextChanged events to no effect - 
mostly problems getting implemented.

Can anyone suggest any errors I might have in first two lines, or alternative choice. Is/are there any Properties in the TextBox I should be looking at.

TIA   Day Watson

Comment: You can subscribe the PreviewKeyDown event and set e.IsInputKey = True when you see the Tab key.  You now get ChrW(9) in your KeyPress event handler.  Hard to see how that can be useful, if you use it to change the focus then, well, the Tab key of course already does that.

Comment: Thanks Hans for  your guidance.  Have achieved what I wanted with

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        Me.Text = "TAB Captured" 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Hans for your guidance -difficult at 75 to keep up with VB developments.  My amended handler now as follows: